# Best practice for using Maven or Gradle without internet access

Tags: maven, gradle, offline

My company has a policy that software deployed into production has be be built on a specific machine that has no access to the internet.

We're currently using `Maven`. When running build on development machines, maven automatically download the dependencies from central Maven repository without problem. Then before go production, we put all files in local Maven repository (.m2/repository) into source control, and then run offline build with

```
  mvn -o -Dmaven.local.repo=<local repo dir> package
```

this method works, but managing thousands of files in source control is a real pain, particularly the dependencies for Maven plugins. Thus my question, how can I **improve the workflow** so as to make it easier to maintain the dependencies in the source control?

I'm considering switching to `Gradle`, mainly because it's more flexible and doesn't depend on plugin downloaded from repository. but then I found out the Gradle local cache directory is not transportable between computers, which means I cannot check it into source control.

Suggestions and recommendations are all appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you put .m2/repository into source control, rather than just copying it between machines?

Comment: Why not using a repository manager which solves that problem.

Comment: Internal repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory

Answer (score 2):

Use internal repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory. Always put released artefact to production.

But building project on production machine is not good idea. Better use complete artefact like EAR or WAR with all dependencies included, or something like jar-with-dependencies or other assembled distros. Build project on your CI server and deploy complete package with one click to production server.